# Dissolve second select statement

Tags: mysql, select

I got following query which is as well working.

```
SELECT date, duration, educationDepartment, yearOfTraining, completedtasks 
FROM programm_completedtask 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-08-05' AND '2014-08-08' 
  AND trainee_id = 
    (SELECT id FROM programm_trainee WHERE username = 'Markus');
```

Is it possible to do anything else instead of the second select statement ? I would love to just select once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an INNER JOIN ...

```
SELECT p.date, p.duration, p.educationDepartment, p.yearOfTraining, p.completedtasks 
FROM programm_completedtask as p
INNER JOIN programm_trainee as pt on p.trainee_id = pt.id AND  pt.username = 'Markus'
WHERE p.date BETWEEN '2014-08-05' AND '2014-08-08'
```

or

```
SELECT p.date, p.duration, p.educationDepartment, p.yearOfTraining, p.completedtasks 
FROM programm_completedtask as p
INNER JOIN programm_trainee as pt on p.trainee_id = pt.id 
WHERE p.date BETWEEN '2014-08-05' AND '2014-08-08' 
AND  pt.username = 'Markus'
```